# What is the equivalent of PHP's geoip_isp_by_name function?

Tags: python, django, geoip

I need the equivalent of [geoip_isp_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-isp-by-name.php). I am using [Django GeoIP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) module.

I search a lot and I couldn't find the function. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pygeoip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoip/0.2.6) has support for ISP lookup using a GeoIP database.

```
# Normally found under /usr/share/GeoIP/{GeoIP,GeoIPv6}.dat
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIPISP.dat')
gi.org_by_name('cnn.com')
'Turner Broadcasting System'
```

The installation process of a GeoIP database depends on your operating system and distro. It's normally available in your favorite distro's repository under `geoip-database`. For more information take a look at [GeoIP Country Database Installation Instructions](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/install/country)

Sadly, I could not get it to work, I got an error on both my Ubuntu 12.10 and Debian 6 installation, but I'm not sure if my GeoIP database is corrupt or the module is broken. You might have better luck.

```
gi.org_by_name("cnn.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygeoip/__init__.py", line 548, in org_by_name
    return self.org_by_addr(addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygeoip/__init__.py", line 531, in org_by_addr
    raise GeoIPError(message)
GeoIPError: Invalid database type, expected Org, ISP or ASNum
```

**Update**: Since GeoIP wouldn't work (see comments), I played around a little bit with the use of those tracer sites. Got a hacky solution that works for both IPs and hostnames. Should probably not be used as a permanent solution, but it works just fine.

```
import html2text
import re
import urllib2

lookup = "thevoid.no" # accepts both hostname and ip

tracer = "http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/"
pat    = "ISP of this IP \[\?\]:\n\n([a-zA-Z ]+)"
hdr    = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} # ip-adress.com doesn't accept Python
req    = urllib2.Request(tracer + lookup, headers=hdr)
page   = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_links = True
text = h.handle(page)

try:
    # Hetzner Online AG
    print re.search(pat, text).group(1)
except:
    print "Could not find ISP for", lookup
```

**Update 2**: Got an [answer](https://github.com/appliedsec/pygeoip/issues/34#issuecomment-16614353) to my issue. There's [seperate GeoIP databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable#Binary-Databases-1), and the [Org edition](https://www.maxmind.com/en/organization) can be found here, but seem to cost money. I'm not sure if there's a free alternative in Python, or someone sharing their API. If not, my hacky solution might be it.

Comment: I made a new [issue](https://github.com/appliedsec/pygeoip/issues/34) on their [Github repo](https://github.com/appliedsec/pygeoip). I'll update my answer if/when I get an answer.

Comment: @AdamSilver I added a hacky alternative solution. Take a look and see if it's ok for your use case.